# Change the div background-image on SlideToggle in a Repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, background-image, repeater, slidetoggle

I have an ItemTemplate where I am using SlideToggle to show/hide the content.
I want to change the image(up/down arrow) while SlideToggle. Please see the below code: For some reason, when I am using the replace method, the image doesn't change and the SlideToggle doesn't work either.
Could someone suggest a correct way to do it.

```
<ItemTemplate> 
<div class="memData">

   <div id="blueBar">
       <div id="Title"><%# Eval("title") %> </div>

       <asp:ImageButton style="margin-left:420px;" ID="ImageButton1" width="60" Height="60" ImageUrl="~/Content/images/down_arrow_white.png" runat="server" />

    </div>

    <div id="Description" style="display:none;" >
        <p> <%# Item.Description %></p>
     </div>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Here is the jQuery I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('[id*="blueBar"]').click(function () {

            $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");


            var down = $("#ImageButton1").attr('src') == "~/Content/images/down_arrow_white.png"

            $("#ImageButton1").attr(
                'src',
                $("#ImageButton1").attr('src').replace(down ? 'down_arrow_white' : 'up_arrow_white', down ? 'up_arrow_white' : 'down_arrow_white')
            );

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your jQuery part as below, as your ImageButton1 would get a dynamic `ID` when the page is rendered by `ASP.net`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id*="blueBar"]').click(function () {
            $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");

            //findng the image button id from the repeater row 
            var imageButtonID = $(this).child().find('[id$=ImageButton1]').attr('id');

            var down = $("#" + imageButtonID).attr('src') == "~/Content/images/down_arrow_white.png";

            $("#" + imageButtonID).attr(
                'src',
                $("#" + imageButtonID).attr('src').replace(down ? 'down_arrow_white' : 'up_arrow_white', down ? 'up_arrow_white' : 'down_arrow_white')
            );

        });

    });
<script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! I am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'child'"

Comment: @bunnie check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685231/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-object-htmlelement-has-no-method-parent) so question to help you resolve this error. You might have missed the `$` sign.